# Illegal Request error with unmap on vmware

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, filesystems, scsi, vmware-vsan

I have enabled unmap feature on vSAN and then I powered off / powered on all VMs to enable unmap as described in the KB below.

https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.7/com.vmware.vsphere.virtualsan.doc/GUID-C75E80AE-2DA8-4314-98E5-B7F8CE98E1BF.html

After these procedures I successfully completed *unmap* on all VMs with *fstrim* and also enabled *fstrim.timer* to schedule to run this once a week.

So far everything is normal.

After a few weeks I noticed that some VMs have the following logs  but as I mentioned above fstrim has worked successfully before.

There is no change in Ubuntu OS version, kernel version or fstrim version.

Is this issue OS related or vSAN related or should I use an alternative tool to unmap, any suggestions?

fstrim output:

```
> journalctl -u fstrim

systemd[1]: Starting Discard unused blocks...
fstrim[15063]: /mnt/abc: 8.5 GiB (9084649472 bytes) trimmed
fstrim[15063]: /: 1.8 GiB (1896648704 bytes) trimmed
systemd[1]: Started Discard unused blocks.
systemd[1]: Starting Discard unused blocks...
fstrim[9262]: /mnt/abc: 0 B (0 bytes) trimmed
fstrim[9262]: /: 829.2 MiB (869523456 bytes) trimmed
systemd[1]: Started Discard unused blocks.
systemd[1]: Starting Discard unused blocks...
fstrim[2672]: /mnt/abc: 0 B (0 bytes) trimmed
fstrim[2672]: /: 913.5 MiB (957837312 bytes) trimmed
systemd[1]: Started Discard unused blocks.
systemd[1]: Starting Discard unused blocks...
fstrim[1792]: /mnt/abc: 0 B (0 bytes) trimmed
fstrim[1792]: /: 395.1 MiB (414277632 bytes) trimmed
systemd[1]: Started Discard unused blocks.
systemd[1]: Starting Discard unused blocks...
systemd[1]: fstrim.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
fstrim[3591]: fstrim: /mnt/abc: FITRIM ioctl failed: Remote I/O error
fstrim[3591]: fstrim: /: FITRIM ioctl failed: Remote I/O error
systemd[1]: fstrim.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start Discard unused blocks.
systemd[1]: Starting Discard unused blocks...
fstrim[1750]: fstrim: /mnt/abc: FITRIM ioctl failed: Remote I/O error
fstrim[1750]: fstrim: /: FITRIM ioctl failed: Remote I/O error
systemd[1]: fstrim.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
systemd[1]: fstrim.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start Discard unused blocks.
```

dmesg output:

```
> dmesg
sd 32:0:1:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 32:0:1:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
sd 32:0:1:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Invalid field in cdb
sd 32:0:1:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Unmap/Read sub-channel 42 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00
print_req_error: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 184820928
sd 32:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 32:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
sd 32:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Add. Sense: Invalid field in cdb
sd 32:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Unmap/Read sub-channel 42 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00
print_req_error: critical target error, dev sda, sector 82568
```

sg utils output:

```
> sg_vpd /dev/sdb -p lbpv
Logical block provisioning VPD page (SBC):
  Unmap command supported (LBPU): 1
  Write same (16) with unmap bit supported (LBWS): 0
  Write same (10) with unmap bit supported (LBWS10): 0
  Logical block provisioning read zeros (LBPRZ): 0
  Anchored LBAs supported (ANC_SUP): 0
  Threshold exponent: 1
  Descriptor present (DP): 0
  Minimum percentage: 0
  Provisioning type: 2
  Threshold percentage: 0

> sg_vpd /dev/sda -p lbpv
Logical block provisioning VPD page (SBC):
  Unmap command supported (LBPU): 1
  Write same (16) with unmap bit supported (LBWS): 0
  Write same (10) with unmap bit supported (LBWS10): 0
  Logical block provisioning read zeros (LBPRZ): 0
  Anchored LBAs supported (ANC_SUP): 0
  Threshold exponent: 1
  Descriptor present (DP): 0
  Minimum percentage: 0
  Provisioning type: 2
  Threshold percentage: 0

> sg_inq /dev/sdb -d
standard INQUIRY:
  PQual=0  Device_type=0  RMB=0  LU_CONG=0  version=0x06  [SPC-4]
  [AERC=0]  [TrmTsk=0]  NormACA=0  HiSUP=0  Resp_data_format=2
  SCCS=0  ACC=0  TPGS=0  3PC=0  Protect=0  [BQue=0]
  EncServ=0  MultiP=0  [MChngr=0]  [ACKREQQ=0]  Addr16=0
  [RelAdr=0]  WBus16=1  Sync=1  [Linked=0]  [TranDis=0]  CmdQue=1
    length=36 (0x24)   Peripheral device type: disk
 Vendor identification: VMware  
 Product identification: Virtual disk    
 Product revision level: 2.0 

> sg_inq /dev/sda -d
standard INQUIRY:
  PQual=0  Device_type=0  RMB=0  LU_CONG=0  version=0x06  [SPC-4]
  [AERC=0]  [TrmTsk=0]  NormACA=0  HiSUP=0  Resp_data_format=2
  SCCS=0  ACC=0  TPGS=0  3PC=0  Protect=0  [BQue=0]
  EncServ=0  MultiP=0  [MChngr=0]  [ACKREQQ=0]  Addr16=0
  [RelAdr=0]  WBus16=1  Sync=1  [Linked=0]  [TranDis=0]  CmdQue=1
    length=36 (0x24)   Peripheral device type: disk
 Vendor identification: VMware  
 Product identification: Virtual disk    
 Product revision level: 2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

when you use unmap to reclaim space, this task should be done on LUNs  in this case on VSAN. I see on your images that linux servers is trying to run fstrim but it is not necessary. On vmware, you can configure space reclamation, select your LUN, configure, general and set space reclamation automatic.
Another question, why you present ISCI luns with vsan? Whats use case?